# How to show menu dynamically in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show menu in laravel dynamically.

I have two table, One holds Main Category and other one Holds Sub category

Here is the structure of Category table

```
  ----------------------------------
  | id | title   | slug  |  type   |
  | 1  | title1  | slug1 | Android |
  | 2  | title2  | slug2 | Android |
  | 3  | title3  | slug3 | Android |
  | 4  | title4  | slug4 | Ubuntu  |
  | 5  | title5  | slug5 | Ubuntu  |
  ----------------------------------
```

Sub Category Structure

```
  -----------------------------------------------
  | id | title   | slug  | category_of|
  | 1  | title1  | slug1 | 1          |
  | 2  | title2  | slug2 | 1          |
  | 3  | title3  | slug3 | 1          |
  | 4  | title4  | slug4 | 2          |
  | 5  | title5  | slug5 | 1          |
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Here is What I've tried

```
<?php
    $category = App\Models\Menu::where('categories.type', 'Android')
                ->select('categories.*', 'sub_category.slug as sub_slug', 'sub_category.title')
                ->join('sub_category', 'sub_category.category_of', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->get();
            ?>
   @foreach ($category as $value)

<li class="inner-dropdown-item">
    <p>
  <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$value->slug}}/">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $value->slug))}}</a>
    </p>
  </li>

  <li class="inner-dropdown-item">
      <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$value->sub_slug}}/{{$value->sub_slug}}">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $value->sub_slug))}}</a>
  </li>

 @endforeach
```

The Problem I'm facing is, it is duplicating  main category every time due to foreach loop, for e.g

```
<li class="inner-dropdown-item">
    <p>
       <a href="/category/android/">Android</a>
    </p>
</li>

<li class="inner-dropdown-item">
     <a href="/category/android/calendars">Calendars</a>
</li>

     <!-- /INNER DROPDOWN ITEM -->

<!-- /This Below Android category should not be shown again -->
<li class="inner-dropdown-item">
    <p>
       <a href="/category/android/">Android</a>
    </p>
</li>

<li class="inner-dropdown-item">
    <a href="/category/android/database-abstractions">Database Abstractions</a>
</li>
```

As you see it is duplicating main category every time sub category is shown. How can i show Main category Once and then all sub category following under it

I have another Template which has different menu HTML Structure

```
<!-- MENU ITEM -->
                <li class="menu-item sub">
                    <a href="#">
                        Designer
                        <!-- SVG ARROW -->
                        <svg class="svg-arrow">
                            <use xlink:href="#svg-arrow"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <!-- /SVG ARROW -->
                    </a>

                    <div class="content-dropdown">
                        <!-- FEATURE LIST BLOCK -->

                        <?php $m_des = ''; ?>
                        @foreach ($design_category as $des_value)

                            @if($m_des != $des_value->slug)
                            <div class="feature-list-block">
                                <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$des_value->slug}}/">
                                    <h6 class="feature-list-title">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $des_value->slug))}}</h6></a>
                                <hr class="line-separator">
                                <?php $m_des = $des_value->slug; ?>
                                @endif
                                <!-- FEATURE LIST -->
                                <ul class="feature-list">

                                    <li class="feature-list-item">
                                        <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$des_value->slug}}/{{$des_value->sub_slug}}/">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $des_value->sub_slug))}}</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                                <!-- /FEATURE LIST -->
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>

                </li>
                <!-- /MENU ITEM -->
```

It is generating ul and div again and again which causes html errors

Comment: You are using `join` without `group`, therefore you get multiple rows per entry, depending on the number of `sub_categories`

Comment: @colburton 
 
how can i do it by group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better solution for it. But you can try this. Do order by `categories.id` then in loop check main category is printed last time or not

```
<?php
    $category = App\Models\Menu::where('categories.type', 'Android')
                ->select('categories.*', 'sub_category.slug as sub_slug', 'sub_category.title')
                ->join('sub_category', 'sub_category.category_of', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->orderBy('categories.id');
                ->get();
$latest_category = "";
            ?>
   @foreach ($category as $value)
<?php if($latest_category != $value->slug){ ?>
<li class="inner-dropdown-item">
    <p>
  <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$value->slug}}/">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $value->slug))}}</a>
    </p>
  </li>
<?php 
$latest_category = $value->slug;
} ?>
  <li class="inner-dropdown-item">
      <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$value->sub_slug}}/{{$value->sub_slug}}">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $value->sub_slug))}}</a>
  </li>

 @endforeach
```

**EDIT**

```
<div class="content-dropdown">
                        <!-- FEATURE LIST BLOCK -->

    <?php $m_des = ''; 
    $end_div = '';
    ?>
    @foreach ($design_category as $des_value)

        @if($m_des != $des_value->slug)
        {{$end_div}}
        <div class="feature-list-block">
            <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$des_value->slug}}/">
                <h6 class="feature-list-title">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $des_value->slug))}}</h6></a>
            <hr class="line-separator">
            <?php $m_des = $des_value->slug; 
            $end_div = "</div>";
            ?>
            @endif
            <!-- FEATURE LIST -->
            <ul class="feature-list">

                <li class="feature-list-item">
                    <a href="{{ Config::get('constants.url.BASE_URL') }}category/{{$des_value->slug}}/{{$des_value->sub_slug}}/">{{ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $des_value->sub_slug))}}</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <!-- /FEATURE LIST -->        
    @endforeach
    {{$end_div}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your method Work

Comment: check edited answer and let me know its working or not

Comment: Is it possible to show ul tag only once in main category then show it again in next category, because in this way ul tag is also being populated again and again

Comment: apply same logic for `ul`